# Creating webapp with Node.js and Firebase/Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've built an iOS/firestore app.  I'm now looking to create a web app to integrate with my database.  I was going through the documentation and found a distinction between firebase for Node.js (https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) and firebase firebase admin SDK (https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

I believe that I will want admin privileges and control over the web app but since I'm learning this for the first time should I focus on the basics of getting user auth, access to the database, storage and cloud functions working?  Or will be changing/adding the admin privileges down the line be such a hassle that it's better to struggle through it now?

I'm still new to the web side of firebase and I'm trying to get a feel for the approach I should take.

Answer (score 1):

If you're building a web interface for your app, I'd encourage you to use the Firebase JS SDK and do most of the work client-side. It should be pretty similar to what you've already done in iOS.

You should only use the Admin SDK if you're specifically trying to create endpoints with custom trusted functionality that isn't available by using the normal SDKs.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense, just out of curiosity do you have an example of the custom trusted functionality that you mentioned?  I'm just curious even if I don't plan doing anything in that area.

Comment: It's the kinds of things we talk about in [What Can You Do With Cloud Functions?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases)